# Insert Query NO ERROR BUT NO RESULT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert the result from mathematichs function in this table

open_list table

```
+----------+----------+
+  id      + result   +
+----------+----------+
```

and this is my source

```
$result="select markers_tujuan.lng,markers_tujuan.lat,open_list.lat, open_list.lng,
((SQRT((((markers_tujuan.lat-markers_tujuan.lng)*(markers_tujuan.lat-markers_tujuan.lng)) + ((open_list.lat-open_list.lng)*(open_list.lat-open_list.lng)))))(sqrt((((markers_tujuan.lat-open_list.lat)*((markers_tujuan.lat-open_list.lat)))+((markers_tujuan.lng-open_list.lng)*((markers_tujuan.lng-open_list.lng))))))) as hasil
from markers_tujuan, open_list";
$result2= mysql_query($result);

$result=$result2;
$try="INSERT INTO open_list(result) VALUES '$result'";
$result3= mysql_query($try);
```

but no query is added :(

Comment: `VALUES ('$hasil')` . Have you even looked in the error log?Or use `mysql_error()`?

Comment: @Notulysses no error ,i try this "select markers_tujuan.lng,markers_tujuan.lat,open_list.lat, open_list.lng,
((SQRT((((markers_tujuan.lat-markers_tujuan.lng)*(markers_tujuan.lat-markers_tujuan.lng)) + ((open_list.lat-open_list.lng)*(open_list.lat-open_list.lng)))))(sqrt((((markers_tujuan.lat-open_list.lat)*((markers_tujuan.lat-open_list.lat)))+((markers_tujuan.lng-open_list.lng)*((markers_tujuan.lng-open_list.lng))))))) as hasil
from markers_tujuan, open_list" . in mysql, and get the result

Comment: Do you mind adding the result of print_r($result2); and before $result3 a print_r($try)

Is the connection string working? (did you try a php simple query?)

Comment: You are missing the point, try: `INSERT INTO open_list(hasil) VALUES ('$hasil')` Note the parantheses around $hasil.

Comment: @Lennart It didn't work :(